# Code execution not happening in asyn function

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following code the last line does not print ('end'):

```
function setTimeoutSync(fn, milli) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(fn, milli);
    });
}

async function run () {
    console.log('start');
    await setTimeoutSync(() => { console.log('setTimeoutSync'); }, 3000);
    console.log('end');
}

run();
```

It is not that the script is exiting, because nothing I put after the `await` statement gets executed.

How can NodeJS just not execute statements in a function? Also, what's a good way to do a good old-fashioned synchronous wait in NodeJS? This question is actually more about the former than the latter.

Comment: You forgot to call `resolve`, so the Promise never resolves

Comment: When I call `resolve` it prints 'end' before 'setTimeoutSync'.

Comment: See the linked question on how to convert a callback API to promises

Comment: You should not pass a callback to a function that returns a promise

Comment: there's nothing sync about `setTimeoutSync`, even if you call it like that. Better write a simple promise-wrapper for setTimeout `const wait = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));` and use it as `await wait(3000); console.log('setTimeoutSync'); console.log('end');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a typo but you forgot to call `resolve` so the next line after the `await` will execute:

```js
function setTimeoutSync(fn, milli) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fn()
      resolve()
    }, milli);
  });
}

async function run() {
  console.log('start');
  await setTimeoutSync(() => {
    console.log('setTimeoutSync');
  }, 3000);
  console.log('end');
}

run();
```

As for your question:

> Can you explain how not calling resolve can result in the rest of the
>   function not executing?...

Well [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) uses [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) behavior:

> The purpose of async/await functions is to simplify the behavior of
>   using promises synchronously and to perform some behavior on a group
>   of Promises. Just as Promises are similar to structured callbacks,
>   async/await is similar to combining generators and promises.

A generator can [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) results thus not terminating the execution context, and can continue it where it left off.

Basically your example could be written with [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) callback:

```js
function setTimeoutSync(fn, milli) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fn()
      resolve()
    }, milli);
  });
}

async function run() {
  console.log('start');
  setTimeoutSync(() => {
    console.log('setTimeoutSync');
  }, 3000)
  .then((result) => {
   console.log('end');
  });
  
}

run();
```

So as you see, if we are not resolving, the callback to `.then` won't run.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how not calling `resolve` can result in the rest of the function not executing? Is it causing the `run` function to return early? I would expect a runtime error if statements in a function were not executable.

Comment: It was not knowing that `generators` existed that confused me. Now it makes sense. Thanks!